# Array Addressing

Tags: arduino-ide, array, ide, code-optimization

Is it possible to use a name instead of a number to address an array? I was reading about enum lists and thought it might be possible.
ie 
int array[3] = {something, somethingElse, somethingMore]

array[second] => somethingElse

I am asking as I have an array looking after flags for several functions and would like to be able to use the function name instead of a number to address the array.

```
bool flag[6] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}; // Power, Jump 3, Jump 7, Fade 3, Fade 7, Pause active
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a generic programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can use a `struct`:

```
struct flags {
    uint8_t power;
    uint8_t jump3;
    uint8_t jump7;
    .... etc ....
};

struct flags myFlags;

myFlags.power = 1;
if (myFlags.jump3) {
    .... stuff ....
}
```

Or you can continue to use a simple numeric array and assign names to the numbers, either with `#define`, `const` variables, or an `enum`.

```
enum flags {
    power, jump3, jump7, fade, fade7, pause
};

bool flag[6] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};

flag[power] = 1;
if (flag[jump3]) {
    .... whatever ....
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, ill give them a go.

Comment: Used the struct method, works perfectly :) thanks